# how do i connect sqlplus as sudo to oracle user using python subprocess module?

Tags: python, sqlplus, sudo

I have a python script owned by root user and i'm trying to run sqlplus commands as sudo to oracle user.But getting issues like oracle_home not set

```
import os,subprocess
query = '''
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEAD OFF
SET EMB ON PAGES 0 NEWP
SET LINE 10000
SELECT * from dual;
EXIT;
'''
dbsession = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/sudo","-u","oracle","/orahome/Database/db12c/bin/sqlplus", "-S", "/ as sysdba"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,env={"ORACLE_SID": "EMREP", "ORACLE_HOME": "/orahome/Database/db12c"})
dbsession.stdin.write(query)
query_result = dbsession.communicate()
print(query_result, dbsession.returncode
```

#### output

```
(('', 'Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus\nSP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found\nSP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory\n'), 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The below code worked

```
import os,subprocess
query = '''
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEAD OFF
SET EMB ON PAGES 0 NEWP
SET LINE 10000
SELECT * from dual;
EXIT;
'''
db_home=/orahome/Database/db12c
dbsession = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/sudo","su","-","oracle","-c",""""""""+db_home+"""/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba"""""], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,env={"ORACLE_SID": "EMREP", "ORACLE_HOME": "+db_home+"})
dbsession.stdin.write(query)
query_result = dbsession.communicate()
print(query_result, dbsession.returncode)
```

Answer (score 0):

passing 'env' to Popen only works when also specifying 'shell=True' and you did not. So this worked because luckily someone alredy set the environment variables at user session level for you :)